# Numbering each equation, and, have a large curly brace around them

Tags: equations, align

I can create a curly brace around a set of equations (aligned at two positions!) using `aligned`:

```
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}[2]
    &\rho   &&= \frac{\e^{- \lambda_2 \H/k}}{\e^{1 + \lambda_1/k}}
    \\
    &\Tr{\rho} &&= 1 
    \\
    &\Tr{\rho \H} &&= \braket{E} 
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Or, I can create a set of equations where every line has a number, but no curly brace, using `alignat`:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
    &\rho   &&= \frac{\e^{- \lambda_2 \H/k}}{\e^{1 + \lambda_1/k}}
    \\
    &\Tr{\rho} &&= 1 
    \\
    &\Tr{\rho \H} &&= \braket{E} 
\end{alignat}
```

[image]

How can I create a set of equations (still aligned at two positions) that all have numbers (like in the second example), and they *also* have a curly brace (like in the first example)??

Comment: It was pointed out to me that this question has a very neat duplicate here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases, however none of the answers there address the case when the equation is aligned at two positions.

Comment: I have in fact found an elegant solution inspired by an answer at the near duplicate, but it seems I cannot add my solution as long as the question is flagged as duplicate. If you think my reasons for why this is different is enough, you can un-flag it and I will add my solution.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150695/82917 contains a solution, though the formulation of the question is different, so not an exact dupe.

Answer (score 6):

It was pointed out that there exist a [near duplicate to the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases). However none of the answers there specifically address the situation where we have equations (and not conditions), and *here* the equations should be aligned at several points.

I was able to create the following solution after reading the answers in the near duplicate, using the [empheq](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package, in combination with `alignat`.

```
\begin{empheq}[left={\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
    &\rho &&= \frac{\e^{- \lambda_2 \H/k}}{\e^{1 + \lambda_1/k}}
    \\
    &\Tr{\rho} &&= 1 
    \\
    &\Tr{\rho \H} &&= \braket{E} 
\end{empheq}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's easy enough to fake the alignment using box measurements - something made easy using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cases,eqparbox,xparse}

\newcommand{\faketerm}[1][1]{\rule{#1 em}{1ex}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{}
  \eqmathbox[lhs][l]{\faketerm[4]} = \faketerm[5] \\
  \eqmathbox[lhs][l]{\faketerm[3]} = 1            \\
  \eqmathbox[lhs][l]{\faketerm   } = \faketerm[2]
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

---

If you don't have any "explanations", then you can `\unskip` the additional space used between them as a replacement for your alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cases}

\newcommand{\faketerm}[1][1]{\rule{#1 em}{1ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{}
  \faketerm[4] &\unskip {} = \faketerm[5] \\
  \faketerm[3] &\unskip {} = 1            \\
  \faketerm    &\unskip {} = \faketerm[2]
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```